# JSON_OBJECT vs. JSON_ARRAY in MySQL result set

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a result set in JSON format from MySQL. As far as I can see, MySQL is capable [returning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html) the entire result set as:

- `JSON_OBJECT`
- `JSON_ARRAY`

In which format it is common to return a result set — as a `JSON_ARRAY` or to wrap it firstly with `JSON_OBJECT`?

Comment: From a performance point of view on both ends (the database and caller), there is not much difference.  So, I guess it is up to your own personal preference.

Comment: JSON_ARRAY will return data with numbered indices, so you will have to access data as $data[0], $data[1] etc. and JSON_OBJECT will return associative array with key-value pairs. It is up to your use-case as to which one you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some exploration, I came up with an conclusion that since DB-engine returns a set of results, which can contain 0+ elements, it's more intuitive/expected to return an array, rather than an object, which will contain already an array of items.

Besides that, since a result set may contain more than one item, we will be forced to use an array anyway. Therefore, if we decide to return a `JSON_OBJECT`, we have to wrap a result set/array with some service property, which adds extra getter-call on accessing the data, e.g.:

```json
{
    "results": […]
}
```